# se puede imprimir usando servicio de windows con pribilegios elevados?

Tags: c#, .net, servicio, print

construi hace poco un servicio de windows en C# y .NET para imprimir, funciona pero
el unico inconveniente es que imprime solo si configuro el servicio con la cuenta de usaurio local de windows, de lo contrario envia al averno la impresion.

alguein me ayudar como solucionarlo.

deseo que la impresion no nececite de configurar esta cuenta, ya que si cambia de sesion o cambia la contraseña de su ceunta se estropearia.

dato adicional
para imprimir use PrintDocument
con una rutina de codigo como esta.

```
       #region
        this.printattender = new PrintDocument();
        PrinterSettings psthree = new PrinterSettings();
        printattender.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
        printattender.PrinterSettings = psthree;
        printattender.PrintPage += Imprimirmodulo;
        #endregion
        
        public void Imprimirmodulo(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Obj_eventlog02.WriteEntry("Imprimiendo Tiket " + Id_internal_day);
        Font hf = new Font("Arial", 50, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        Font he = new Font("Arial", 45, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);

      ......
          ....
   e.Graphics.DrawString(Namerz, h1, Brushes.Gray, new Rectangle(imgwi + space, y += 3, despues, altob += 30), formatRight);
    .....
    ....
```

**Editado 10-11-2021**

miren como son las cosas... hoy me tope con un insidente con este servicio que comente.
lo ejecute sin nececidad de configurar la cuenta y que creen?
imprimio...
asi que le echo mano a la razon del porque y me di cuenta que el sistema no imprime en las otras computadoras por que la cuenta de sistema local no ve la impresora en su lista es como si no estaria instalada para ella.

asi que instale la impresora como local y vualaaaaaa!, imprimio.

asi que la solucion era instalar la impresora en esta forma y nada mas.

saludos.

Comment: Para responder, se utiliza la parte inferior donde dice `Tu Respuesta`. Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

**Editado 13-11-2021**

Una brebe lectura.

Diseño del mecanismo de integridad de Windows
07/05/2007
39 minutos de lectura

El mecanismo de integridad de Windows es una extensión de la arquitectura de seguridad de Windows, que se basa en el Monitor de referencia de seguridad del kernel. El monitor de referencia de seguridad aplica el control de acceso comparando los SID de usuario y grupo en el token de acceso de seguridad con los permisos de acceso otorgados en la ACL del descriptor de seguridad de un objeto. El mecanismo de integridad agrega un nivel de integridad al token de acceso de seguridad y una entrada de control de acceso de etiqueta obligatoria a la ACL del sistema (SACL) en el descriptor de seguridad.

**Las partes principales del mecanismo de integridad son:**

Niveles de integridad predefinidos y su representación.
Políticas de integridad que restringen los permisos de acceso.
Nivel de integridad asignado al token de acceso de seguridad.
Entrada de control de acceso de etiqueta obligatoria.
Etiquetas obligatorias asignadas a los objetos.
Restricciones de integridad dentro de las API de AccessCheck y SeAccessCheck en modo kernel.
Cada una de estas partes se describe con más detalle a continuación. El mecanismo de integridad de Windows siempre está en vigor, independientemente de otras opciones de política de seguridad. Las comprobaciones del nivel de integridad, como las comprobaciones de control de acceso, no son opcionales. No hay opciones de política de seguridad para deshabilitar las verificaciones de nivel de integridad. Aunque el mecanismo de integridad es compatible con UAC, el mecanismo de integridad permanece en vigor cuando UAC está deshabilitado por la directiva de grupo de seguridad.

**Niveles de integridad**
Windows define los niveles de integridad mediante el uso de un SID. El uso de un SID para representar un nivel de integridad facilita la integración del mecanismo de integridad en las estructuras de datos de seguridad existentes sin requerir cambios de código. Los SID de nivel de integridad tienen la siguiente forma: S-1-16-xxxx. La Tabla 1 muestra los componentes de los SID de nivel de integridad.

Tabla 1 Valores de autoridad del identificador SID del nivel de integridad
TABLA 1 VALORES DE AUTORIDAD DEL IDENTIFICADOR SID DEL NIVEL DE INTEGRIDAD
Valor   Descripción
16

Representa la autoridad de etiqueta obligatoria (SECURITY_MANDATORY_LABEL_AUTHORITY).

xxxx

Representa el campo de identificador relativo (RID) que es el nivel de integridad. El RID es un valor hexadecimal que representa el nivel de integridad.

Hay cuatro niveles de integridad principales en Windows con cuatro valores correspondientes. Un valor más bajo indica un nivel de integridad más bajo o un nivel más bajo de confiabilidad. Estos valores se definen en el archivo de encabezado, winnt.h. La Tabla 2 muestra los niveles de integridad definidos y sus valores correspondientes.

Tabla 2 Niveles de integridad definidos y valores correspondientes
TABLA 2 NIVELES DE INTEGRIDAD DEFINIDOS Y VALORES CORRESPONDIENTES
Valor   Descripción Símbolo
0x0000

Nivel no confiable

SECURITY_MANDATORY_UNTRUSTED_RID

0x1000

Nivel de integridad bajo

SECURITY_MANDATORY_LOW_RID

0x2000

Nivel de integridad medio

SECURITY_MANDATORY_MEDIUM_RID

0x3000

Alto nivel de integridad

SECURITY_MANDATORY_HIGH_RID

0x4000

Nivel de integridad del sistema

SECURITY_MANDATORY_SYSTEM_RID

Un ejemplo de un SID de nivel de integridad medio es esta cadena: S-1-16-8192. El valor RID de 8192 es el equivalente decimal de 0x2000.

Los RID están separados por intervalos de 0x1000 para permitir la definición de niveles adicionales en el futuro. La separación también permite asignar un nivel de integridad a un proceso que es ligeramente superior al medio: por ejemplo, para cumplir con los objetivos específicos del diseño del sistema.

Los SID de nivel de integridad definidos tienen valores de nombre de cadena asociados con ellos. El uso de API LookupAccountSID devolverá nombres de cadena para cada SID de nivel de integridad. La Tabla 3 muestra los nombres de las cadenas para los niveles de integridad.

Tabla 3 Nombres de cadenas de niveles de integridad
TABLA 3 NOMBRES DE CADENAS DE NIVELES DE INTEGRIDAD
Nivel de integridad SID Nombre
S-1-16-4096

Etiqueta obligatoria \ Nivel obligatorio bajo

S-1-16-8192

Etiqueta obligatoria \ Nivel obligatorio medio

S-1-16-12288

Etiqueta obligatoria \ Nivel obligatorio alto

S-1-16-16384

Etiqueta obligatoria \ Nivel obligatorio del sistema

Los niveles de integridad también se definen como cadenas de SID en el lenguaje de definición de descriptores de seguridad (SDDL). El SDDL define el formato de cadena que utilizan las funciones ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor y ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor para describir un descriptor de seguridad como una cadena de texto. El lenguaje también define elementos de cadena para describir información en los componentes de un descriptor de seguridad. El uso de SDDL para definir los niveles de integridad hace que sea conveniente definir el nivel de integridad de un objeto cuando se crea el objeto. Para obtener más información sobre las cadenas de SID para los niveles de integridad, consulte Recursos del mecanismo de integridad de Windows . El soporte SDDL para etiquetas obligatorias se describe en el Apéndice A: SDDL para etiquetas obligatorias .

Windows usa SID de nivel de integridad en el token de acceso de seguridad para representar el nivel de integridad del sujeto y usa SID de nivel de integridad en la etiqueta obligatoria ACE en un descriptor de seguridad para representar el nivel de integridad del objeto.

Políticas de integridad
Esto significa que las políticas limitan el tipo de acceso que los objetos de nivel de integridad inferior pueden tener a los objetos de nivel de integridad superior. La Tabla 4 muestra las dos categorías de políticas.

Tabla 4 Categorías de políticas de integridad
TABLA 4 CATEGORÍAS DE POLÍTICAS DE INTEGRIDAD
Categoría   Descripción
Políticas obligatorias del token de acceso

Establezca el token de acceso y determine cómo se aplican las políticas obligatorias al sujeto, que está representado en el token de acceso.

Políticas de etiquetas obligatorias

Establezca la etiqueta obligatoria ACE (descrita a continuación) en los objetos y determine cómo restringir el acceso al objeto.

Las políticas determinan cómo se restringen los derechos de acceso en todos los niveles de integridad.

Políticas de token de acceso obligatorio
La Tabla 5 muestra las políticas de token de acceso obligatorias que se definen en Windows.

Tabla 5 Políticas de token de acceso obligatorio en Windows
TABLA 5 POLÍTICAS DE TOKEN DE ACCESO OBLIGATORIO EN WINDOWS
Política    Descripción
TOKEN_MANDATORY_NO_WRITE_UP

La política predeterminada que se asigna a todos los tokens de acceso. La política restringe el acceso de escritura de este sujeto a cualquier objeto con un nivel de integridad superior.

TOKEN_MANDATORY_NEW_PROCESS_MIN

**Controla el comportamiento de asignar el nivel de integridad a los procesos secundarios. Normalmente, un proceso hijo hereda el nivel de integridad del proceso padre cuando el token de acceso del proceso padre se asigna al hijo. Con la política NEW_PROCESS_MIN, el nivel de integridad del proceso hijo será el nivel mínimo de integridad del token de acceso principal o el nivel de integridad del objeto del archivo ejecutable para el nuevo proceso. Esta política se establece de forma predeterminada en todos los tokens de acceso.**

La política NEW_PROCESS_MIN se puede describir con un ejemplo. Suponga que hay un programa ejecutable llamado lowcalc.exe. Al archivo de programa se le asigna una etiqueta de baja integridad. Desde un símbolo del sistema, el usuario ejecuta lowcalc.exe. El proceso principal, cmd.exe, se ejecuta a un nivel de integridad medio. Debido a que el archivo de imagen, lowcalc.exe, tiene una etiqueta de baja integridad, la política NEW_PROCESS_MIN establece el nivel de integridad del nuevo proceso, lowcalc, en bajo. Esto se ilustra en el ejemplo siguiente en la sección Diseño de aplicaciones para que se ejecuten a un nivel de integridad bajo .

Políticas de etiquetas obligatorias
Las políticas de etiquetas obligatorias se definen como banderas (bits) en el campo Máscara de la entrada de control de acceso de etiquetas obligatorias. Estos indicadores de política determinan las restricciones sobre los permisos de acceso que se aplican a los sujetos de menor integridad. La Tabla 6 muestra las políticas de etiquetas obligatorias que se definen en Windows.

Tabla 6 Políticas de etiquetas obligatorias en Windows
TABLA 6 POLÍTICAS DE ETIQUETAS OBLIGATORIAS EN WINDOWS
Política    Descripción
SYSTEM_MANDATORY_POLICY_NO_WRITE_UP

La política predeterminada en todas las etiquetas obligatorias de los objetos. La bandera es equivalente a la política de token de acceso NO_WRITE_UP. La política restringe el acceso de escritura al objeto por parte de un sujeto con un nivel de integridad más bajo.

SYSTEM_MANDATORY_POLICY_NO_READ_UP

Restringe el acceso de lectura al objeto por parte de un sujeto con un nivel de integridad más bajo. La política se utiliza, por ejemplo, para restringir el acceso de lectura al espacio de direcciones de la memoria virtual de un proceso.

SYSTEM_MANDATORY_POLICY_NO_EXECUTE_UP

Restringe el acceso de ejecución al objeto por parte de un sujeto con un nivel de integridad más bajo. La política se utiliza, por ejemplo, para restringir los permisos de activación de lanzamiento en una clase COM por sujetos de menor integridad.

Estas políticas definidas cumplen los objetivos de diseño de Windows. La arquitectura del mecanismo de integridad permite una expansión futura mediante la definición de opciones de políticas adicionales que controlan los permisos de acceso entre sujetos y objetos en diferentes niveles de integridad.

Cómo se asignan las políticas de integridad a los derechos genéricos
La verificación de políticas obligatoria ocurre como parte de la función de seguridad de AccessCheck. AccessCheck (y SeAccessCheck en modo kernel) tiene como uno de los parámetros de función una estructura GENERIC_MAPPING. El mapeo genérico proporcionado por el llamador mapea los derechos de acceso específicos del objeto a las categorías genéricas de lectura, escritura y ejecución. Las políticas de etiquetas obligatorias implementan restricciones sobre el acceso permitido en función de las categorías genéricas. Para un tipo de objeto en particular, GENERIC_MAPPING comunica a la verificación de política obligatoria qué derechos de acceso específicos están prohibidos.

Si la estructura GENERIC_MAPPING que se pasa a una llamada a AccessCheck es todo ceros (0), el mapeo genérico no está definido. Cuando el mapeo genérico no está definido, la verificación de políticas obligatoria restringe todos los derechos de acceso de los sujetos de menor integridad. Los administradores de recursos que usan AccessCheck para la seguridad de objetos privados y pasan una estructura GENERIC_MAPPING de todos ceros verán errores de Acceso denegado . **Se requiere un cambio de código en la aplicación del administrador de recursos para asignar los derechos de acceso específicos del tipo de objeto a los derechos de acceso genéricos que impone la política obligatoria.**

Cómo se asignan los niveles de integridad a los tokens de acceso
El token de acceso de seguridad es una estructura de datos interna que utiliza el kernel. El token de acceso de seguridad contiene diferentes valores de información que corresponden a privilegios, pertenencia a grupos y otros detalles relacionados con la seguridad.

El kernel asigna un token de acceso a cada proceso e hilo. El token de acceso principal del proceso contiene el nivel de integridad asociado con ese proceso. En el mecanismo de integridad de Windows, el nivel de integridad del proceso se denomina nivel de integridad del sujeto. Si el token de acceso de una aplicación contiene el SID de integridad media, el proceso de la aplicación se está ejecutando a un nivel de integridad media. A varios procesos de aplicación que se ejecutan bajo la misma cuenta de usuario se les asigna el mismo token de acceso principal. Así es como a cada una de las aplicaciones se le asigna el mismo nivel de integridad.

Los niveles de integridad se asignan a los tokens de acceso según los SID de grupos específicos que están presentes en la estructura TOKEN_GROUPS. El kernel de Windows asigna un nivel de integridad basado en cuentas de grupo o usuario integradas específicas. Windows asigna un token de acceso que tiene el SID de la cuenta del sistema local presente el nivel de integridad del sistema, un token de acceso con el SID del grupo de administradores local presente se asigna el nivel de integridad alto y un token de acceso para una cuenta de usuario estándar se asigna el nivel de integridad del medio.

La Tabla 7 muestra las asignaciones del nivel de integridad al token de acceso, según la presencia de SID específicos.

Tabla 7 Niveles de integridad vinculados a SID específicos
TABLA 7 NIVELES DE INTEGRIDAD VINCULADOS A SID ESPECÍFICOS
SID en token de acceso  Nivel de integridad asignado
LocalSystem

Sistema

Servicio local

Sistema

Servicio de red

Sistema

Administradores

Elevado

Operadores de respaldo

Elevado

Operadores de configuración de red

Elevado

Operadores criptográficos

Elevado

Usuarios autenticados

Medio

Todos (mundo)

Bajo

Anónimo

Desconfiado

Los niveles de integridad definen diferentes niveles de confiabilidad para las aplicaciones que se ejecutan en diferentes niveles de acceso. La mayoría de las aplicaciones en Windows se ejecutan en un nivel de acceso de usuario estándar en el nivel de integridad medio. Las aplicaciones en el nivel de integridad medio no experimentan restricciones sobre cómo interactúan con otras aplicaciones y con los datos en el nivel de integridad medio. Las tareas o aplicaciones específicas que requieren derechos administrativos se ejecutan con un alto nivel de integridad. Los servicios del sistema se ejecutan en el nivel de integridad del sistema, porque existen restricciones en su capacidad para interactuar con el escritorio predeterminado y, a menudo, se ejecutan con poderosos privilegios del sistema. Algunas aplicaciones que han sido diseñadas para ejecutarse con la menor cantidad de derechos posibles, como Internet Explorer en modo protegido, pueden ejecutarse con un nivel de integridad bajo.

Ciertos privilegios administrativos de Windows se pueden asignar a un token de acceso solo con al menos un alto nivel de integridad. Si el nivel de integridad del token de acceso es menor que alto, no se permiten privilegios administrativos específicos y se eliminan del token de acceso. Los privilegios administrativos asociados con un alto nivel de integridad son:

SE_CREATE_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE
SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE
SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_PRIVILEGE
SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE
SE_RESTORE_PRIVILEGE
SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE
SE_IMPERSONATE_PRIVILEGE
SE_RELABEL_PRIVILEGE
SE_LOAD_DRIVER_PRIVILEGE
Las aplicaciones pueden asignar un nivel de integridad bajo a un token de acceso duplicado al crear un proceso hijo. Windows puede ejecutar un proceso de aplicación con un nivel de integridad bajo si el archivo de imagen del programa ejecutable tiene una etiqueta obligatoria baja. Estas funciones se describen más adelante en este artículo.

Cómo obtener el nivel de integridad de un token de acceso
El nivel de integridad se almacena en el token de acceso mediante el campo TOKEN_GROUPS. La estructura TOKEN_GROUPS es una lista de SID y atributos que identifica las membresías de grupo para esa cuenta de usuario. El nivel de integridad del token de acceso también se identifica en la lista de grupos mediante un atributo SID. La estructura SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES contiene el nivel de integridad SID, y el nivel de integridad se identifica mediante los atributos SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY y SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY_ENABLED.

Puede recuperar el nivel de integridad del token de acceso del token de acceso mediante la API GetTokenInformation. GetTokenInformation tiene un parámetro para indicar qué clase de información de token de acceso recuperar. El parámetro TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS tiene un valor definido para el nivel de integridad, TokenIntegrityLevel. La estructura de datos devuelta es de tipo TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL.

Para determinar el nivel de integridad de un proceso

Abra un identificador para el token de acceso del proceso.

Obtenga el nivel de integridad del token de acceso.

Compare el SID del nivel de integridad con los RID del nivel de integridad definidos por el sistema.

En el Apéndice D se muestra un código de ejemplo para obtener el nivel de integridad del token de acceso.

Cómo ver el nivel de integridad de un token de acceso
El nivel de integridad en el token de acceso de seguridad de un proceso se puede ver utilizando herramientas que exponen los detalles de seguridad de un proceso, como Process Explorer de SysInternals.com. Las siguientes imágenes muestran la pantalla de Process Explorer con la columna Integrity Level agregada a la vista (a la derecha).

Figura 1 Nivel de integridad en Process Explorer

Si miramos las propiedades de seguridad de un proceso específico, como explorer.exe, Process Explorer muestra el nivel de integridad en la lista de grupos que están definidos en el token de acceso de seguridad del proceso. La siguiente imagen muestra la etiqueta obligatoria / nivel obligatorio medio asignado al token de acceso para el proceso, explorer.exe.

Figura 2 Explorer.exe como un proceso de nivel de integridad medio

Cómo establecer el nivel de integridad para un token de acceso
Las aplicaciones generalmente no necesitan cambiar el valor del nivel de integridad del proceso. Por lo general, las aplicaciones no necesitan realizar cambios en ninguno de los valores del token de acceso de seguridad. Sin embargo, en algunas circunstancias, los servicios que dan soporte a clientes locales en diferentes niveles de integridad pueden optar por realizar tareas en un nivel de integridad más bajo. La suplantación es una forma en que un subproceso de servicio puede ejecutarse en un nivel de integridad más bajo. Cuando un subproceso de servicio se hace pasar por un cliente local, el subproceso de suplantación tiene el contexto de seguridad del cliente, que incluye el nivel de integridad del cliente si el cliente se ejecuta en la misma máquina local.

Para establecer el valor de un nivel de integridad del token de acceso en un hilo

Llame a OpenThreadToken para obtener un identificador del token de acceso.

Llame a GetTokenInformation con el valor del parámetro TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS de TokenIntegrityLevel para guardar el nivel de integridad del hilo actual.

Llamada SetTokenInformation con el TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS valor del parámetro de TokenIntegrityLevel .

Debido a que no existe un límite de seguridad dentro de un espacio de direcciones de proceso entre subprocesos en diferentes niveles de integridad, los diseñadores de aplicaciones deben considerar los riesgos de seguridad potenciales de tener código ejecutándose en un subproceso con menor integridad ejecutándose en un proceso de mayor integridad. La mayoría de las aplicaciones pueden encontrar más sencillo crear un proceso separado que se ejecute en el nivel de integridad más bajo para realizar tareas de integridad más baja.

Un ejemplo de cómo configurar TokenIntegrityLevel y crear un proceso en un nivel de integridad más bajo se muestra en Cómo configurar el nivel de integridad para un token de acceso.

Etiqueta obligatoria ACE
El mecanismo de integridad de Windows define un nuevo tipo de ACE, la etiqueta obligatoria del sistema ACE. La etiqueta obligatoria ACE se utiliza para representar la etiqueta obligatoria de un objeto en el descriptor de seguridad del objeto. La etiqueta obligatoria contiene el nivel de integridad y la política de integridad asociada. Una etiqueta ACE obligatoria se usa solo en la ACL del sistema, o SACL, del descriptor de seguridad. La SACL es un campo separado en el descriptor de seguridad de la ACL discrecional (DACL).

Figura 3 Campos del descriptor de seguridad

La ACL discrecional contiene permisos de acceso de usuarios y grupos al objeto. Cualquier usuario o grupo puede realizar actualizaciones a la DACL con permisos de acceso a objetos WRITE_DAC. Las ACL discrecionales se pueden actualizar con más frecuencia y por diferentes usuarios. Uno de los objetivos del diseño del mecanismo de integridad es que el sistema de seguridad debe mantener la etiqueta con un objeto después de que se le aplique una etiqueta obligatoria. La aplicación de la etiqueta obligatoria apropiada en el descriptor de seguridad del objeto, con poco o ningún impacto en las aplicaciones diseñadas para administrar ACL, se logra colocando la etiqueta obligatoria en la ACL del sistema, donde está principalmente bajo el control del sistema de seguridad. La etiqueta obligatoria está lógicamente separada de las entradas de auditoría del sistema en la SACL.

La etiqueta obligatoria ACE es similar a una ACE con acceso permitido, ya que contiene un encabezado ACE, una máscara de acceso y un SID. La parte SID de la etiqueta obligatoria ACE contiene el SID del nivel de integridad. La Tabla 8 muestra los campos en el encabezado ACE.

Tabla 8 Campos contenidos en el encabezado ACE
TABLA 8 CAMPOS CONTENIDOS EN EL ENCABEZADO ACE
Campo de encabezado ACE Valor
AceType

UIPI no interfiere ni cambia el comportamiento de la mensajería de ventana entre aplicaciones en el mismo nivel de privilegio (o integridad). UIPI evita que los procesos con privilegios bajos accedan a procesos con privilegios más altos bloqueando el siguiente comportamiento. Un proceso con privilegios más bajos no puede:

Realice una validación de identificador de ventana de un proceso que se ejecuta con derechos más altos.
Utilice SendMessage o PostMessage para las ventanas de la aplicación que se ejecutan con mayores derechos. Estas API devuelven el éxito, pero eliminan silenciosamente el mensaje de la ventana.
Utilice ganchos de hilo para adjuntar a un proceso que se ejecuta con derechos más altos.
Utilice enlaces de diario para supervisar un proceso que se ejecuta con mayores derechos.
Realice una inyección de biblioteca de vínculos dinámicos (DLL) en un proceso que se ejecute con derechos superiores.
Con UIPI habilitado, los siguientes recursos de USUARIO compartidos aún se comparten entre procesos en diferentes niveles de privilegios.

Ventana de escritorio, que en realidad posee la superficie de la pantalla
Memoria compartida de solo lectura del montón de escritorio
Tabla de átomos global
Portapapeles
Pintar en la pantalla es otra acción que no está bloqueada por UIPI. El modelo de interfaz de usuario / dispositivo gráfico (GDI) no permite el control sobre las superficies de pintura. Por lo tanto, una aplicación que se ejecuta con menos derechos puede pintar sobre la superficie de la ventana de la aplicación para una aplicación que se ejecuta con más derechos.

UIAccess para aplicaciones de automatización de UI
La automatización de la interfaz de usuario de Microsoft es el modelo de Windows para admitir los requisitos de accesibilidad con mejoras sobre el modelo anterior, conocido como Microsoft Active Accessibility (MSAA). **Las aplicaciones diseñadas para admitir una experiencia de usuario accesible controlan el comportamiento de otras aplicaciones de Windows en nombre del usuario. Cuando todas las aplicaciones (el cliente y el servidor de automatización) se ejecutan como un usuario estándar, es decir, a un nivel de integridad medio, las restricciones de UIPI no interfieren con el modelo de automatización de la interfaz de usuario.**

Sin embargo, puede haber ocasiones en las que un usuario administrativo ejecute una aplicación con privilegios elevados según UAC en el modo de aprobación de administrador. El programa de automatización de la interfaz de usuario no podrá controlar la interfaz de usuario de gráficos de aplicaciones elevadas en el escritorio sin la capacidad de eludir las restricciones que implementa UIPI. La capacidad de eludir las restricciones de UIPI en SendMessage a través de los niveles de privilegios está disponible para los programas de automatización de la interfaz de usuario que utilizan un atributo de seguridad especial en el manifiesto de la aplicación del programa, conocido como UIAccess .

El siguiente es un ejemplo de una entrada de manifiesto de aplicación para un programa UIAccess.

Al especificar UIAccess = ”true” en el atributo requiredPrivileges , la aplicación establece un requisito para eludir las restricciones de UIPI sobre el envío de mensajes de ventana a través de los niveles de privilegios. Windows implementa las siguientes comprobaciones de políticas antes de iniciar una aplicación con privilegios UIAccess.

La aplicación debe tener una firma digital que pueda verificarse mediante un certificado digital que se conecte a una raíz de confianza en el almacén de certificados de las Autoridades de certificación de la raíz de confianza de la máquina local.
La aplicación debe instalarse en un directorio de aplicaciones de carpeta local en el que solo los administradores puedan escribir, como el directorio Archivos de programa. Los directorios permitidos para las aplicaciones de automatización de la interfaz de usuario son:
% ProgramFiles% y sus subdirectorios.
% WinDir% y sus subdirectorios, excepto algunos subdirectorios que están excluidos porque los usuarios estándar tienen acceso de escritura.
Los subdirectorios% WinDir% que son subdirectorios excluidos incluyen:

\Depurar
\Salud de la PC
\Registro
\ System32 \ ccm
\ System32 \ com
\ System32 \ FxsTmp
\ System32 \ Spool
\ System32 \ Tasks
Windows proporciona una configuración de seguridad para la política del equipo local y para la Política de grupo para ajustar el requisito de que los programas UIAccess deben iniciarse desde ubicaciones seguras. La configuración se define en las Opciones de seguridad en las Políticas locales para las Políticas de seguridad locales. La política de seguridad es la siguiente:

Control de cuentas de usuario: solo eleve las aplicaciones UIAccess que estén instaladas en ubicaciones seguras

Este ajuste está activado por defecto. Sin embargo, un administrador puede deshabilitarlo si hay situaciones en las que las aplicaciones UIAccess (tecnología accesible) que deben iniciarse desde carpetas no están protegidas por el acceso de escritura exclusivo del administrador.

Si la aplicación de automatización de la interfaz de usuario que solicita UIAccess cumple con los requisitos de configuración de UIAccess, Windows inicia la aplicación con la capacidad de eludir la mayoría de las restricciones de UIPI. Si la aplicación de automatización de la interfaz de usuario no cumple con las restricciones de seguridad, la aplicación se iniciará sin derechos de UIAccess y solo podrá interactuar con aplicaciones del mismo nivel de privilegios o de un nivel inferior.

Un proceso que se lanza con derechos UIAccess:

Tiene la capacidad de configurar la ventana de primer plano.
Puede manejar cualquier ventana de aplicación usando la función SendInput.
Tiene entrada de lectura para todos los niveles de integridad utilizando ganchos de bajo nivel, entrada sin procesar, GetKeyState, GetAsyncKeyState y GetKeyboardInput.
Puede colocar ganchos de diario.
Utiliza AttachThreadInput para adjuntar un hilo a una cola de entrada de mayor integridad
A las aplicaciones que se inician con derechos UIAccess para un usuario estándar se les asigna un valor de nivel de integridad ligeramente superior en el token de acceso. El nivel de integridad del token de acceso para la aplicación UIAccess para un usuario estándar es el valor del nivel de integridad medio, más un incremento de 0x10. El nivel de integridad más alto para las aplicaciones UIAccess evita que otros procesos en el mismo escritorio en el nivel de integridad medio abran el objeto de proceso UIAccess

**Resumen**

Por Politica de seguridad desctrita y resumida lineas arriva un cada usuario tiene acceso a los servicios y aplicaciones que le corresponde.

lo que significa que mi servicio aunque corre y posee pribilegios de administrador, no podra acceder a una capa mas abajo por que esto le pertenece a la cuenta del sistema y se nececita como minimo:

Iniciar una aplicación con privilegios UIAccess.

La aplicación debe tener una firma digital que se pueda verificar mediante un certificado digital que se encadena a una raíz de confianza en la máquina local Trusted Root Almacén de certificados de las Autoridades de Certificación.

La aplicación debe instalarse en un directorio de aplicaciones de carpeta local en el que solo los administradores puedan escribir, como el directorio Archivos de programa.

**Resumen del Resumen**

Instalar la impresora como local solucionar este problema.

**PD1: link de info
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/bb625963(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

PD2: si el link cae la info quedara Aqui.**

Comment: por que instalar la impresora como local soluciona el problema??? cual es la diferencia; me parece que aunque esto solucione tu problema no es una respuesta de buena calidad; le falta una explicación mas detallada.

Comment: crei que habia sido totalmente claro al mencionar que "por que la cuenta de sistema local no ve la impresora en su lista es como si no estaria instalada para ella." pero si eso no te sirve entonces busca esta referencia https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/share-your-network-printer-c9a152b5-59f3-b6f3-c99f-f39e5bf664c3

Comment: hola, no es que yo lo diga es que no lo dice tu respuesta incluso la respuesta de Microsoft puede quedarse sin soporte en el futuro y el link que acabas de agregar fácilmente puede estar roto en un par de años... cosas que suele hacer los de MS...